# Expand a Div Vertically to fit contents

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have **Login** page, with a **div** in the center. I have set the height and it fits perfectly. However, if I add **validation errors** at the top of the **div**, the **button** at the bottom gets pushed outside the **div**. The page is a bit more complicated, but I have simplified it to the following HTML and CSS

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content">
        <form action="/Account/LogIn" method="post">
            <div id="login" name="login">
                <div id="validation-errors">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            One or more errors here
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <label>Email:</label> <input type="email" name="email"> <br/>
                <label>Password:</label> <input type="password" name="password"> <br/>
                <input id="loginBtn" type="submit" value="Login" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
 </html>
```

And **CSS**:

```
#content {
     position: absolute;
     top: 50%;
     left: 0px;
     width: 100%;
     height: 0px;
     overflow: visible;
     visibility: visible;
     display: block;
 }
 #login {
     background-color:#85ADFF;
     width: 350px;
     height: 100px;
     position: absolute;
     top:-100px;
     bottom:0;
     left:0;
     right:0;
     margin:auto;
 }
 #loginBtn {
     float: right;
}
```

You can view it at http://jsfiddle.net/9jA2F/

What changes should I make so that the **Login** button stays in the Blue box **div** even when **validation errors** are displayed. If you delete the **validation error div**, it seems to work fine i.e. the button is within the Blue box **div**.

Comment: The problem is that your centering is based on the height you set on the div, and that changes when the validation adds code to the div.

Comment: Thank you **j08691**. I think I needed to remove both **height** and **bottom** from the #login CSS to get this to work - as **Cody Guldner** suggested below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This method will give you **true** vertical and horizontal centering regardless of the content height (based on [this article](http://www.jakpsatweb.cz/css/css-vertical-center-solution.html))

```
#content {
    display: table;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

#content form{
    top: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: static;
}

#login {
    background-color:#85ADFF;
    width: 350px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    position: relative;
    top: -50%;
    text-align: left;
}
```

**[Check out the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9jA2F/9/)**

Comment: Thank you very much **koala_dev**. I think your suggestion went beyond correcting the problem with the code in my original post. I liked your suggestion regarding setting the `#content` to `display: table;`, and then the `#content form` to `display: table-cell;` with `vertical-align: middle;` and finally the `#login` margins to `auto`. This improved my original code :-) and fixed my problem.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you put `bottom:0;` on `#login`. I'm not entirely sure why this would break it, but if you remove that, it works.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9jA2F/5/)

Comment: Thank you **Cody Guldner**. Removing `bottom:0;` and the `height` in `#login` did it for me.

Answer (score 1):

Delete `height: 100px;` and `top: -100px;` from `#login`.

Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/9jA2F/8/ .

```
#content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 0px;
    overflow: visible;
    visibility: visible;
    display: block;
}

#login {
    background-color:#85ADFF;
    width: 350px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    margin:auto;
}

#loginBtn {
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: Thank you **ITChristian**. This is similar to suggestion by **Cody Guldner**. It seems that I have to remove the `height`, and either one of the `bottom` or `top` from `#login`. I'd be grateful if someone has an explanation for this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/44w37/1/)

I couldn't resist designing all the way ;)

The problem was that once you float an element (like a button) it comes out of the flow, and thus the container doesn't include it in the calculated auto height.

To make the button float right but still not actually float:

```
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you **ThatWeirdo** that looks very nice! I was not looking at making this look pretty - but thanks for the tips, because as I mentioned in my original post, this is a simplification, not my real code. As far as your suggestion to changing the CSS of the button, I could not get this to work. As others suggested, the way is to get rid of the `height` and either the `top` or `bottom`.

Answer (score 0):

Check updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/9jA2F/4/

```
#loginBtn {
position: absolute;
right: 0; bottom: 0;
}
#login {
background-color:#85ADFF;
width: 350px;
height: 100px;
position: relative;
top:-100px;
bottom:0;
left:0;
right:0;
margin:auto;
}
```

Comment: Thank you **Mihai**. As others suggested, I think I needed to remove the height at the minimum, because if I have more errors, then the Email and the Password text boxes get outside **login** div i.e. Blue box.

Answer (score -2):

Why don't you let the div expand with height:auto, and give it padding to maintain the distance between the elements and the borders of the div.  That way it can stretch if errors are populated and shrink if no message is present.  The error on your jsfiddle does not disappear so I can't test it, but start here and keep trying!